# I don't understand the exact meaning " It might be that~"

Tags: existentials

> Finally, sharing an experience is appealing to more adventurous travelers. It might be that walking tour of street art in San Francisco.

I don't know exactly what "It might be that" is meaning.

Is there any different meaning when I use "It is that walking tour~" instead of " It might be that~"?

Also, in "It might be that walking~", is it right to use 'the' instead of that?
if I can or not, what is different between them.

Answer (score 1):

> If you are looking for an answer to your question, **it might be that** this one is the one you choose.

The writer, quoted in the question, is offering a suggestion or an example as an illustration to the reader.

If you change it to "It is that walking tour" then you change the meaning from a suggestion to a recommendation or, maybe, even an instruction.

In the last part of the question, 'that' and 'the' have a subtle difference and would often be interchangeable depending on the context. Using the definite article, "the walking tour", on its own, suggests that there may be only one, conversely, the indefinite article "a walking tour" suggests one from many. "That walking tour" sounds like it is referring to a specific tour that has been previously referred to.